# What version of python is running

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pip

I installed python version 2.7.14 from the python downloader but my Windows server 2016 still showing 2.7.6

```
C:\python --version
    python 2.7.6
```

How do I remove 2.7.6? It is not in Program Files. Not installed by pip.

Answer (score 0):

try finding it with `where python` and then removing it

if your new version of python is installed somewhere else and not added to the path yet you'll also have to do that in order to call it

e.g.

```
C:\Users\gense>where python
C:\Tools\Python36\python.exe
C:\Tools\Python27\python.exe
```